# RegEx find any characters define

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to check if this characters () are  exists in the text.

Characters : `\ / : * ? " < > |)`

If my expression is like this :

```
/^[\\\/\:\*\?\"\<\>\|\)]*$/.test('?')
```

It returns true

However if my expression is like this:

```
/^[\\\/\:\*\?\"\<\>\|\)]*$/.test('asdf?')
```

It returns false

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `^` and possibly `$`: the `^` character means your characters must be at the beginning of the string, `$` means they must be at the end of your string.

`/[\\\/\:\*\?\"\<\>\|\)]*/.test('asdf?')`

Note that the above also matches a blank string; use a quantifier if you want to match at least one:

`/[\\\/\:\*\?\"\<\>\|\)]+/.test('asdf?')`

Comment: it is always return true even the characters define is not present

Comment: `*` version matches even zero characters; use the `+` version (example two) if you want to match at least one.